# Open JIRA issues from inside Vim based on JIRA tag

Tags: vimscript, netrw

I just learned about the `gx` command to open URLs from Vim.  Is there a way to do the same thing based on the highlighting.  For example, I have this match rule to hightlight JIRA issues:

```
syn match JIRA 'TS[IW]-\d\+'
```

I would like to click on the JIRA issue and go to the corresponding web page.  For example, if I click on `TSW-12345` then it should go to `https://jira.example.com/browse/TSW-12345`.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of `gx` by netrw uses `netrw#BrowseX()`. So, for example:

```
const s:jira = 'TS[IW]-\d\+'
function GetJiraTicketUnderCursor() abort
  let word = expand('<cWORD>')
  if word =~# s:jira
    return word->matchstr(s:jira)
  endif
  let line = getline('.')
  let curcol = getcurpos()[2]
  let match = matchstrpos(line, s:jira)
  while match[1] >= 0 && !(match[1] <= curcol && curcol <= match[2])
    let match = matchstrpos(line, s:jira, match[2]+1)
  endwhile
  return match[1] >= 0 ? match[0] : ''
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>J :call netrw#BrowseX('https://jira.example.com/browse/'.GetJiraTicketUnderCursor(), 1)<enter>
```

or, using syntax groups:

```
const s:jira = 'TS[IW]-\d\+'
" Return syntax name of cursor location.
function SyntaxGroupsUnderCursor() abort
  return synstack(line('.'), col('.'))->map({ _, v -> synIDattr(v, 'name'})
endfunction

function GetJiraTicketUnderCursor() abort
  if SyntaxGroupsUnderCursor()->index('JIRA') >= 0
    return expand('<cWORD>')->matchstr(s:jira)
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>J :call netrw#BrowseX('https://jira.example.com/browse/'.GetJiraTicketUnderCursor(), 1)<enter>
```

Comment: I've edited the code to be a bit cleaner.  Once the edits have been approved I will accept your answer.

Comment: @StephenRasku I've restored the original code (with edits) and tweaked what you provided. I'm generally averse to edits on code in answers; you can always supply your own if you have different code. Note that your version didn't handle nested syntax groups, whereas my fixes to yours will and neither of mine cared about them. That probably won't matter because you didn't allow the syntax group to be contained in anything, but you probably will want that at some point.

Comment: I also prefer to (where possible, and the number of target side effects is small) return data from functions: they're easier to test. You could still put the body of the mapping in its own function, if you wish, but having a function that simply returns the ticket number (rather than opening the browser) separates the goal of finding the ticket and the goal of opening it.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply; I was on holidays.  It appears that your new solution requires the regex to maintained in two places; the syntax file and the script.  I would prefer if it was only in the syntax file.  Otherwise, they could get out of sync.

Comment: You could store it somewhere else (globally?) and use `:execute` in your syntax file. But you still need the regex to extract matches (I’m not aware of an API to get all the text matching a syntax group).

Comment: OK, I see why this is necessary.  If there's a word character next to the JIRA tag (e.g. a colon), `<cWORD>` will extract more than the highlighted characters.  There's probably another way to extract the proper characters but this works.